# 2.5 inch laptop hard drive in desktop?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Toshiba MQ01ABD032 250gig laptop hard drive. I was wondering if I could hook it up to my desktop pc. Will it be fried from the 12volt line on the sata power connector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a laptop hard-drive be used in a desktop machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/451079/can-a-laptop-hard-drive-be-used-in-a-desktop-machine)

Comment: Marked dupe question does not deal with power, which is the specific point of this Q.

Comment: @music2myear Only marked as duplicate, based on the title of the question.  Other considerations, such as power, aren't necessary to delve into because of the standardization of SATA.  No aggression meant, however.

Comment: No aggression perceived. As the linked Q only mentioned SATA in passing it could be easy to miss. I noted this and thought this question was just different enough to be not actually duplicate.

Comment: @music2myear, the other asks "can you do it?"  Power isn't specifically addressed, but if it was an issue, wouldn't that be mentioned in the answers as a problem in trying to do it?  This question only asks whether power is an issue, so it seems covered by the other.  If it asked "why" it is or isn't an issue, that would seem like more of a different question.  Good answer, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your drive will not fry on the desktop SATA power connector.

The SATA standard is designed to handle this gracefully. The 15-pin SATA power connector contains 3.3V, 5V, and 12V connectors, and the device will connect to the appropriate pins depending on its needs.

**Pins**

1. 3.3V Power
2. 3.3V Power
3. Enter/Exit Power Disable mode
4. Ground
5. Ground
6. Ground
7. 5V Power, Pre-Charge
8. 5V Power
9. 5V Power
10. Ground
11. Staggered spinup/activity
12. Ground
13. 12V Power, Pre-Charge
14. 12V Power
15. 12V Power

The 2.5" drive, only needing 5V, will only connect to the necessary pins.

For more reading, Wikipedia's article could be a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Power_connectors

Comment: Based on good advice from @JamieHanrahan this answer has been substantially modified. The binary answer did not change, but the explanation of why and the background has been corrected.